# Building Multi-instance (dedicated environment) and Multi-Tenant Applications on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, multi-instance-deployment

I have to implement a hybrid model of application on Azure, where

- a few (20%) of the clients will have dedicated instances
- others (80%) will be based on Multi-tenant (shared) model.

What approach should I take in terms of

- Azure AD (Different AAD Tenants?) - Should i have different sunbscription for each client? As i read that a single subscription can be linked to only 1 Azure AD Tenant.
- VNETs
- App Service
- Logic Apps
  -Service Bus?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The moment you have to sign-in users from more than one tenant, you are advised to carefully study the [multi-tenant app development guide](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant/README.md) to ensure that you understand the nuances of a multi-tenant app development fully.

You have to separate the app's authentication aspect (AAD) from the resource consumption aspect (Azure Subscription).

If you are hosting the app for your customers who do not have a subscription, your app will be most probably registered and deployed in your tenant as a multi-tenant app. You sign-in user's from these customer's tenants but pay for an azure subscription of your own. Then you'd have to figure out how to invoice your customer's to recover the cost of the subscription.

If your app can use a subscription provided by the customer, then your app can be registered and deployed in a customer's tenant and use their resources.